# How to update AWS CloudFront error page response path via CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

Looking for a way to update the CloudFront instance error pages with the command line for continuous integration purposes.

Have had some success with the update-distribution command for the root page but can't seem to figure out how update the the error page response paths. Suggestions? [image: paths]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CloudFront API treats the entire distribution configuration as an atomic entity rather than as individual configurable attributes.

To change a distribution's configuration, it is necessary to fetch the entire configuration using [`aws cloudfront get-distribution`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/get-distribution.html), modify the resulting JSON document by changing what you want to be different, and resubmitting it using [`aws cloudfront update-distribution`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/update-distribution.html).

Note the warning on `update-distribution`:

> **Warning**
>
> The new configuration replaces the existing configuration; the values that you specify in an update-distribution request are not merged into the existing configuration.

Comment: I was thinking that was the case but thanks for clarifying!